What's up with the Community user?
Community seems to have acquired a new name and icon - User -1 is now labeled as 'Community Compiler', with a generated Identicon. On other sites, Community appears unchanged, with the same user profile.
A line has also been added to the About Me:

I do things like... Occasionally touch grass and drink water

Its location also reads inside the gcc compiler which I believe is different.
It seems to be specific to PLDI. Why? Did someone change it?
(Tagging this as bug because it seems unexpected.)

So I don't know if it's supposed to be possible, but turns out moderators can rename the community user. I know this because I'm the reason it's called the community compiler. Why? For science, really. To see if SE would even allow it to happen.
Fun fact: it's been called that since October 2023.
The identicon appeared after the username change. Apparently changing the community user's name changes its icon.

Can you change the profile picture as well?

Only the username @TheEmptyStringPhotographer

But you were also able to edit the About Me

that's correct yes. I meant to say the text options were changeable. @TheEmptyStringPhotographer

Hah hah hah, you were the first suspect. Nice tweak!
